# the URL was ot found (heroku)

Tags: javascript, php, heroku

Empecé a usar heroku pero cuando voy al link solo me aparece el login , después de eso no me deja avanzar y me arroja el error de "404 not found" supongo que son las rutas que tengo pero no tengo idea de a que cambiarlas, otro dato interesante es que cuando hago el "git clone" de mi sitio me hace una copia a medias del proyecto y con esto me refiero a que copia todo menos lo que esta dentro de la carpeta Main_app donde están las validaciones de las sesiones y el proyecto como tal.

### index.js

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#formLg',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:'Main_app/login.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend:function(){
                  $('.botonlg').val('Validando...');
                }
              })
              .done(function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta);
                if (!respuesta.error) {
                  if (respuesta.tipo=='Admin') {
                    location='Main_app/Admin/admin.php';
                  }else if (respuesta.tipo=='User') {
                    location='Main_app/Usuario/usuario.php';
                  }
                }else {
                  $('.error').slideDown('slow');
                  setTimeout(function(){
                  $('.error').slideUp('slow');
                },3000);
                $('.botonlg').val('Iniciar Sesión');
                }
              })
              .fail(function(resp){
                console.log(resp.responseText);
              })
              .always(function(){
                console.log("complete");
            });
      });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen de las carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen del git clone donde se ve que no copio nada del "Main_app"

Comment: git clone es un comando para bajar un repositorio de la nube. ¿Es eso lo que buscas hacer?. y que es lo que estás subiendo a heroku. todas las carpetas como aparece en la imagen de la izquierda o solo lo que está en main_app?

Comment: estoy subiendo todo lo de la izquierda

Comment: lo que busco hacer es subir todo el proyecto a heroku

Comment: entonces tu directorio público solo tiene lo que tienes en THANKS Dig.... en delante quiero suponer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas puede que, como tu mismo dices, sean las `rutas`.
Para acceder a un `path` existen dos formas, la `absoluta` y la `relativa`.
Teniendo de ejemplo tu estructura

```
public_html
|
|--css
|  |
|  |--bootstrap.css
|
|--img
|
|--js
|
|--Main_app
|  |
|  |--Admin
|  |
|  |--Usuario
|  |
|  |--login.php
|
|--composer.js
|
|--index.php
|
|--Procfile
```

para acceder del `index.php` al `bootstrap.css` tienes varias formas

| relativa | relativa | absoluta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ./css/bootstap.css | css/bootstrap.css | /css/bootstrap.css |

Los `path` absolutos son la ruta específica del archivo o carpeta.
El `./` en el primer `path` relativo lo que dice es que el elemento que sigue después del `/`, en este caso la carpeta css, se encuentra al mismo nivel que el `index.php`.
En el segundo `path` nos dice lo mismo al no poner un `/` al inicio.
Ahora desde el caso del login.php.

| relativa | absoluta |
| --- | --- |
| ../css/bootstap.css | /css/bootstrap.css |

El `../` lo que nos dice es que el elemento está un nivel arriba en el `path`
por lo que el sistema lo que hará sera 'subir' un nivel en el `path` y buscar el resto de la ruta.
Se pueden agregar tantos `../` como sean necesarios para ir subiendo niveles en el `path` pero si se llega a la `'raíz'` ya no tendrán efecto los `../` restantes.

En tu caso que quieres llegar a la `path` `Main_app/Admin/admin.php`
tienes la opción de hacerlo de manera `absoluta`.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/Main_app/login.php',
    ...
    }
    if (respuesta.tipo=='Admin') {
        location='/Main_app/Admin/admin.php';
    }else if (respuesta.tipo=='User') {
        location='/Main_app/Usuario/usuario.php';
    }
    ...
);
```

Lo puedes mantener de manera `relativa` sin problemas. Solo revisa bien donde tienes tu `index.js`.